# How would you model this 3D asset from Mike's IOCO / Biocomputer?

Tags: modeling

Do you see a way to model this 3D asset?

Source: [dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/9684522-IOCO-Biocomputer)

Thank you.

[image: ioco1]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Start with the default cube, add a Subdivision Surface Modifier set to 7 Subdivisions (I know it shows 8 in the image - might be too much) - this will turn it into a heavily subdivided "ball" (blender will not let you go to 7 with the arrows, you have to enter it in the box manually).

[image: Shape]

Apply the modifier, then add another Subdivision Surface set to 1 level of subdivisions - this is to give enough geometry for a displacement shader to look "smooth enough". Because of this, you will need to use Cycles Render engine (displacement via shader does not work in eevee.)

[image: Shape2]

To get the shape, I would use a Musgrave texture, because it goes between 1 and -1 and therefore is capable of giving a true "inside out" kind of look. I used a MixRGB node mixed with white to control the intensity and used the whole things as the basis for displacement. To make this work, in the material settings, you must enable "displacement and bump" or "displacement only" (default is bump only):

[image: Shape3]

After this (to better match your image), I would give the object a small Subsurface Scattering value. I would also change the subsurface radius so all three values are equal (Subsurface Scattering is normally used for skin, so red is defaulted to show through more - this sets it back to white).

[image: Shape4]

Lastly, I would just add some colored lights to match the photo - blue to the left and below, pink to the right, and white above:

[image: Shape4]

It's not exactly the same, I know, but it's pretty close. Adjusting some of the values on the Musgrave Texture might get you closer to what you have in mind. You may have to find some creative ways of layering multiple Musgrave Textures to get a better effect. To get it exactly the same, you may want to start with some sort of twisted ribbon instead of a sphere - just remember that the subdivisions are the most important part.

[image: Shape6]

Comment: An *RGB Curves* node might help to get the concavity.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a try, I've plugged a mix of textures into the *Normal* input of a *Principled BSDF*, the *Principled* has a bit of *Subsurface Scattering*, and it is mixed with a *Translucent* node. At the end I've mixed with a *Glossy* with a *Layer Weight* as factor to give it the silk look. I've sculpted the petal. In my opinion the lighting is important too:

[image]

[image]